# Repeat retrofit call with RxJava till condition valid

Tags: rx-java, retrofit2, reactivex

**Problem**: Hit an endpoint till the list of items returned is empty. Every consecutive call will have an updated packetId query param, which is the last item's packetId.

**Setup**: Retrofit2 with Rx adapter

**Attempt**:

```java
MyApiService api = retrofit.create(MyApiService.class);
Observable<Output> call = api.myCall(packetId);
call.repeat().takeUntil(output -> output != null && !output.isEmpty())
    .compose(applySchedulers())
    .subscribe(output -> {
        packetId = output.lastPacketId();
        onFetchOutput(output)
    });
```

Here the packetId won't get updated, since the observable will hit with the same params it was created with.

I can always call this method again once result is fetched.

**Question**: Is there a *reactive way* of doing this? I assume that it will involve some operator which feedbacks the results somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PublishSubject`

```java
private static void test() {
    PublishSubject<Integer> packetSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    packetSubject
            .flatMap(integer -> call()
                    .doOnNext(output -> {
                        if (output == null) {
                            packetSubject.onCompleted();
                        }
                    }))
            .subscribe(output -> {
                if (output != null) {
                    packetSubject.onNext(output.lastPacketId);
                }});
    packetSubject.onNext(1);
}
```